# MySQL: Possible to apply the OR operator across multiple selected rows?

Tags: mysql, operators

I have three MySQL tables: `users`, `roles` and `positions`.

The `users` table is pretty self-explanatory.  The `roles` table is a list of job titles a person might hold, such as `janitor`, `president`, `manager`, etc.  The `roles` table also has a long array of boolean permissions, such as `access_basement` or `user_directory_access`.  If the role has has that bit value set to false (or "0") that role lacks that permission.

Where it gets tricky is that a user might have multiple roles, hence why they are connected by the `positions` table, which is simply a pairing of the `userId` and `roleId` fields.  So if I perform a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
    LEFT JOIN positions ON users.userId=positions.userId
    LEFT JOIN roles ON roles.roleId=positions.roleId 
WHERE users.userId=123
```

I might get results like:

```
+---------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------------+
| name    | title     | basement_access | user_directory_access |
+---------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------------+
| Bob     | Janitor   | true            | false                 |
+---------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------------+
| Bob     | President | false           | true                  |
+---------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------------+
```

Since Bob has two roles, but has different access with each, I'd like to combine the results with a since MySQL query and the logical `OR` operation across all rows, resulting in a table like:

```
+---------+-----------------+-----------------------+
| name    | basement_access | user_directory_access |
+---------+-----------------+-----------------------+
| Bob     | true            | true                  |
+---------+-----------------+-----------------------+
```

So the question is: **is it possible to apply the OR operator across multiple selected MySQL rows?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is if you use values 0 and 1 as role permissions. And use some query like:

```
SELECT u.name, SUM(r.basement_access) AS basement_access, SUM(r.user_directory_access) AS user_directory_access
FROM users  u
  LEFT JOIN positions p ON u.userId=p.userId
  LEFT JOIN roles r ON r.roleId=p.roleId 
WHERE u.userId=123
GROUP BY u.userId;
```

Comment: Yes, and luckily I do use 0 and 1 for my settings, but this requires every field to be enumerated... perhaps it's the only way though.

Comment: As far as I know, there are only two ways: whether use * or name all fields. So, even if some another SQL approach would be used, you still need to name all fields. Or calculate permissions not in database, but in your program. In this case you can iterate over all permissions automatically.